# HTACCESS or PHP Rewrite Query String

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I' am using WordPress and I want to rewrite the query string to clean url.

**Query String**

```
http://example.com/for-farmers-and-growers/members/member-profiles/?username=example
```

**Clean Query String**

```
http://example.com/for-farmers-and-growers/members/member-profiles/example
```

How can I do this in WordPress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set wp to use pretty urls in `Permalink Option Page`:

There are good tutorials [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) and [Here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/seo-friendly-url-structure-for-wordpress/)

Moreover you can use plugins such as [Pretty URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pretty-url/)

For custom query strings check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4598651/1922137)

Comment: It's already on Pretty URL but I have a Custom Query String and I want that Query String to Pretty URL