# change url from query string to normal url

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, url, query-string

i have a site built with wordpress and angularjs. This uses a url structure based on query string like. http://www.carsangrah.com/used-car/?id=171&car-name=Toyota-Etios%20Liva-GD

I want my url to look like http://www.carsangrah.com/used-car/Toyota-Etios%20Liva-GD_i171

How can I change this?

Comment: I think you are looking something like this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597289/wordpress-custom-querystrings-pretty-urls-how 
OR
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586835/how-to-pass-extra-variables-in-url-with-wordpress

Comment: i tried as suggested in https://moz.com/ugc/making-website-urls-seo-friendly-and-pretty. But its not working.